# JavaFX - Remove Element from SwingNode

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Suppose I've done this -

```
SwingNode deviceView = new SwingNode();
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
// Add elements to desktop
deviceView.setContent(desktop);
```

Is there a way remove `desktop` from `deviceView`?  The best way I can come up with is -

```
deviceView.setContent(new JPanel());
```

But is there a way to simply remove it?

---

As noted in the comments I've tried `deviceView.setContent(null);`  which appears to be bugged.

Comment: `setContent(null)` doesn't work?

Comment: @James_D nope, tried that first.

Comment: I guess it is a bug in the Swing integration. The swing node is actually gets removed when using `setContent(null)` (you can try it with a `JButton` which is not clickable anymore) but the `SwingNode` does not get repainted somehow.

Comment: @DVarga yes I've seen that in my attempts too.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this out and let us know how it goes, although I have not tried it out.

```
deviceView.getContent().removeAll();
```

Comment: Doesn't work.  I've added a `JButton` to a `SwingNode` then added an event handler to a JavaFX button which runs `deviceView.getContent().removeAll();` and nothing happens, no error, nothing.  I even tried putting it in a `SwingUtitlities.invokeLater` block.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Late to the party but here is what you could try. 
deviceView.getContent().removeAll();   /****Note : The UI may not show any updates even if you run it inside the SwingUtilities.invokeLater method */

 /**** Now set a new instance that would allow you to set any other content later. At least that is what i have done in one of our Java FX App.*/  
    deviceView = new SwingNode();